# Access local dll with SilverLight 4 out-of-browser

Tags: silverlight, dll, com

I read a little about the new features of Silverlight 4 and it seems possible to 'access' microsoft office . Does this mean that we can reference local dll and COMs ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't reference dlls but you can activate COM objects that have been registered on the local machine.  All you need to know is the CLSID or the ProgID of the COM object you want to create.

```
dynamic myObject = AutmationFactory.GetObject("MyLibrary.MyClass");
```

Comment: OK. That means that theorically, I could use Excel, Word, or other Office API since they are COM, but I won't be able to refenrece them and get the normal commodities of doing so ? ... kinda hate it if it is so.

Comment: @David:  Yep thats about it, you'll not know about any typos until runtime. To mitigate this you might consider creating some Wrapper/Helper classes to minimise the amount of code actually using dynamic types directly.